# $x^{2}<2+\lvert x\rvert$ how to solve algebraically

Tags: inequality

I can easily solve it if I just think about the two functions and then graphing them in my head, however how do I solve this algebraically?

$x^{2}<2+\lvert x\rvert$

Thank a bunch!

Comment: Split into two cases based on the sign of x. This would give you two different quadratic inequalities to solve.

Comment: I did that, but then I get -2<x<1, and -1<x<2

Comment: Which is not right

Comment: do you combine both domains?

Comment: With no cases: $$x^2-(2+|x|)=|x|^2-|x|-2=(|x|-2)(|x|+1)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We split into cases based on the sign of $x$.

Case 1: $x\geq 0$,

The inequality becomes $x^2<2+x$, which implies $(x-2)(x+1)<0$ and thus that $-1<x<2$ From your comment above I guess you got this far. However, you have to remember we are in the case $x>0$, so this range is just $0\leq x<2$. I suggest you try doing the other case yourself, before reading the remainder of my answer below.

Case 2: $x<0$,

The inequality becomes $x^2<2-x$, which gives $(x+2)(x-1)<0$ and hence $-2<x<1$. Remembering the assumption, this case restricts to $-2<x<0$.

We may now take the union of the ranges. Thus the overall answer is $-2<x<2$.

Comment: Once you have done the first case, you can conclude by symmetry since both sides of the equation are unchanged by the transformation $x \to -x$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Since $x^2=|x|^2$ let's make the sustitution $y=|x|$ and solve $y^2-y-2<0$ and consider these values of $y\ge 0$.

Since $y^2-y-2=\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2-\frac{9}{4}$ we have
\begin{align}
y^2-y-2<0 \quad&\iff & \left(|x|-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 &< \frac{9}{4}\\
&\iff & -\frac{3}{2}<|x|-\frac{1}{2}&<\frac{3}{2}
\end{align}

Comment: See coment on main to deal with $y^2-y-2<0$ for nonnegative values of $y$.